# Concatenating a Calculated Percentage in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, concatenation

I have a spreadsheet in excel where I am tracking hires, and then breaking down the total counts in a number of ways.  One is internal vs. external (columns) and there is a different row for each recruiter, and these are subtotaled by recruiting unit.  My bottom row should contain not only the total count, but the percentage.  My total row should appear as follows:

[image]

I have calculated both the sum and the percentage (in cells that are hidden), however when I concatenate these fields the percentage shows simply as the calculated number despite the fact that the cell which the percentage is calculated in being formatted to show a percentage.

I have tried referencing the cell and the % symbol, but the number always shows as the decimal with a % sign, for example:

*Use: =CELL&"%"*

*Get: 0.748148148148148%*

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the only calculation that requires manual intervention.

Comment: Don't concatenate, just apply a percent format.

Comment: This will not work because it is a concatenated field containing the count and the percentage.  Ex: The count is 101, the percentage is 75% (it is a calculated field formatted as a percentage), and I use the following: =CONCATENATE(CELL1,", ",CELL2).  The result displays as "101, 0.748148148148148" - applying the percentage format to this does not work.

Comment: You're creating a string by using concatenate. You need to format each cell component of the string as you want to see it, and force it to show the cell as if it was a % by multiplying by 100.  =CONCATENATE(H2,", ",I2*100,"%")

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, this should solve your problem:

[image: Screenshot(1)]

Formula in cell B17 is:

```
=SUM(B2:B15) & "," & TEXT(SUM(B2:B15)/ SUM(B2:B15,C2:C15)*100,"00") &"%"
```

Formula in cell C17 is:

```
=SUM(C2:C15) & "," & TEXT(SUM(C2:C15)/ SUM(C2:C15,B2:B15)*100,"00") &"%"
```

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: Huzzah!  Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries at all!

Comment: A small suggested improvement -- you could make the formulas more compact and readable with 
Formula in cell B17: 
`=SUM(B2:B15) & "," & TEXT(SUM(B2:B15)/ SUM(B2:C15),"00%")`
Formula in cell C17:
`=SUM(C2:C15) & "," & TEXT(SUM(C2:C15)/ SUM(B2:C15),"00%")`

Comment: Oh nice one @JohnGoodhue ! Thanks, I'll keep that in mind in future.